Limit of a continuous Sobolev function to its boundary
Let $U$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\partial U$ be Lipschitz.
By this   answer, for $u \in W^{1, p}(U)$,
$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{|B_r(x_0)\cap U|} \int_{B_r(x_0)\cap U} |u(y) - u(x_0)|^p = 0$$
for $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$-a.e. $x_0 \in \partial U$.
Now, suppose that $u \in W^{1, p}(U) \cap C(U)$. Then does the following stronger statement holds?:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0, x\in U} u(x) = u(x_0)$$
for $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$-a.e. $x_0 \in \partial U$.

Yes, it holds and you can even remove the continuity assumption on $u$. Indeed, the standard trace theorem holds in a stronger sense, that is if we localize and restrict ourselves to the flat half-space on has an embedding: $$\mathrm{W}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n_+)\hookrightarrow \mathrm{C}^0_{x_n}([0,+\infty),\mathrm{L}^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})).$$
